# Why does my program ask for api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll after the runtime debugging?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new in Visual Studio 2015. Today I tried to do runtime debugging, and after that my program started requiring **api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll** when launching on other PCs. How to fix this?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with debugging, a C or C++ program you build with VS2015 will always have a dependency on this operating system DLL if it was built with /MD.  It is liable to be missing if the machine is old or Window Update has been turned off for a while.  Maybe you can rescue it by installing [the redist](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).  Maybe you shouldn't trust that machine too much, not running Windows Update is a mistake.  Be sure to deploy your Release build.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [refactored the C/C++ Runtime in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) and the `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` is the new C++ Runtime. So you need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587) on all PCs where you want to run your tool.